# Android - How to Generate Key Presses Programmatically

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

After reading through this " [How to Generate Key Presses Programmatically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967178/how-to-generate-key-presses-programmatically-android) " and the associated answers, I created a class that extends `InputMethodService`, but is empty otherwise.

I create an instance of that class and then do something like this `_imsExtend.getCurrentInputConnection()`, but it appears that `getCurrentInputConnection()` returns a *null pointer* and causes issues thereafter.

What am I forgetting to do?  I am guessing I need to setup some of the parameters of `_imsExtend`, but what?