# Handling Back button press event when application not open

Tags: android

I am developing security app on android platform. now my requirement is to handle back button press event when application not open or not in foreground screen.

some code of my application should run, i need to send notification from my application. when three time back button press continuously when app closed

is there any way to handle back button event out of application??
i know how to handle back press event when application currently in use but dont know this type of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidService runs in Background
but it seems not to work outside of an Activity

This Question was asked already here:

[pressing the back button on android through service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430805/pressing-the-back-button-on-android-through-service)

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to handle back button event out of application?

No, sorry.

> i need to send notification from my application. when three time back button press continuously when app closed

That is not possible, sorry.